# Why the vector field $x \frac{d}{dx}$ is complete on the manifold $\mathbb R_+$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

The **vector field** $ \frac{d}{dx} $ over the manifold $ \mathbb R $ is a complete vector field as
the solution of the **integral equations**
$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = 1; 
$$
Has the solution, $x(t) = t + x(0)$ , so the solution can be extended for all $t \in \mathbb R $,

Now, if we remove one single point from $\mathbb R$, i.e $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, then in finite time the solution goes off the manifold at $t=0$, That's why in the modified manifold
the vector field fails to be complete.

Now, If I modify the manifold to be $\mathbb R_+$, Then also in finite time the solution flies off the manifold,  $t \leq 0$, So here also the vector field fails to be a complete vector field.

Now, along the same chain of thought I don't understand why the vector field $x \frac{d}{dx}$ in $\mathbb R_+$ is a complete vector field,
The solution of the integral curve is
$$
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = x(t),\quad x(t) = x(0)e^t
$$
For any $x(0) \in \mathbb R_+ $, the solution goes off $\mathbb R_+$ in finite time, So it should not be called a complete vector?

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: At what finite time does $x(0)e^t$ go off $\Bbb R^+$?

Comment: @Arthur Okay, I see the problem, I am not allowed to take $t <0$ because the manifold is only $\mathbb R_+$,  For when the solution was $t+x(0)$, then only in a finite time $t \to -x(0)$ the solution goes off $\mathbb R_+$, Will I be right in saying this?

Comment: Who says you're not allowed to take $t<0$? It is $x(t)$ which should remain an element of $\Bbb R^+$, for all $t\in\Bbb R$. And this is indeed true for $x(t)=x(0)e^t$. Thus we have a complete vector field.

Comment: @Arthur, My understanding was all wrong, your last comment cleared it all up,